# bwhitmiss on a sparse set of locations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Say I have a huge image `I`, and a set of pixel locations indexed by `pix_locations` (linear indices indexing locations in `I`). I would like to run a hit-and-miss operation (i.e. what [bwhitmiss](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwhitmiss.html) does) with a structuring elements `SE` only on the locations indexed by `pix_locations`.

I know I can just run `bwhitmiss` on the entire image, and then keep the results corresponding to the locations indexed by `pix_locations`, but if the image is large, this is a waste and slow (the locations indexed by `pix_locations` are sparse).

Are there any ways to run `bwhitmiss` selectively on a set of locations on an image?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could partition your image, like a K-d tree, than use the bwhitmiss on the non-empty partitions, but I think as bwhitmiss is a simple look-up table operation you wouldn't benefit much from that micro-optimization unless you have really huge and sparse images.

Comment: I think that BWHITMISS, like many morphological operations, is based on convolution (not a lookup table). The grid-approach is a good advice though, maybe you could use [qtdecomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/qtdecomp.html) for that..

Comment: Basically yes, but for small structuring elements (or structuring elements that can be decomposed to small ones) it could be (partially or fully) substituted to LUT if performance is an issue. http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f18-14868.html

Comment: +1 you are right. Even if that wasn't the case, convolution ought to be highly optimized in MATLAB... For those interested, there is a recent [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/07/08/binary-image-hit-miss-operator/) by Steve Eddins explaining the hit-miss operation.